# nodejs app mongoose database where clause with join

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a schema article defined as:

```
var ArticleSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    content: String,
    creator: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
})
```

And user schema:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    type: String, //editor, admin, normal

    username: String,
    password: String,

})
```

I need to query all the article created by editor, i.e. in sql language

```
select Article.title as title, Article.content as content
from Article inner join User 
on Article.creator = User._id 
where User.type = 'editor'
```

This is what I have tried

```
exports.listArticle = function(req, res, next) {
    var creatorType = req.query.creatorType
    var criteria = {}
    if (creatorType)
        criteria = {'creator.type': creatorType}
    Article.find(criteria).populate('creator').exec(function(err, articles) {
        if (err)
            return next(err)
        //ok to send the array of mongoose model, will be stringified, each toJSON is called
        return res.json(articles)
    })
}
```

The returned `articles` is an empty array `[]`

I also tried `Article.populate('creator').find(criteria)`, also not working with error:

```
utils.populate: invalid path. Expected string. Got typeof `undefined`
```

Comment: You can consider storing the articles in the user collection itself, if there are not going to be too many per user. Have a look at this great article which explains how to design your schema based on your data: http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1

Comment: @ZeMoon let's say if i wanna order the article by createdDate, then populating from user is not gonna help in the speed.

Comment: Well, you can use the aggregation framework for that. There are various ways for you to model your data, each with their own pros and cons. Also, multiple queries are not necessarily a bad thing. JOINS in sql databases cause quite a bit of processing overhead.

Comment: @ZeMoon will it help if I index user's `type` field and article's `creator` field?

Comment: That's an excellent idea! It would definitely make this query lightning fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no concept of joins in MongoDB, as it is a not a relational database.

The populate method is actually a feature of Mongoose and internally uses multiple queries to replace the referred field.

This will have to be done using a multi-part query, first on the User collection, then on the Article collection.

```
exports.listArticle = function(req, res, next) {

    var creatorType = req.query.creatorType
    var criteria = {}
    if (creatorType)
        criteria = {'type': creatorType}

    User.distinct('_id', criteria, function (err, userIds) {

        if (err) return next(err);

        Article.find({creator: {$in: userIds}}).populate('creator').exec(function(err, articles) {
            if (err)
                return next(err)
            //ok to send the array of mongoose model, will be stringified, each toJSON is called
            return res.json(articles)
        })
    })

}
```

Comment: Can i do one query instead of 2? since I already populated `creator`

Comment: Population is done AFTER the query. You can fetch each article, populate the user and then filter them (using forEach()), but that would be too much of an overhead. This is the only way of handling references in MongoDB.

Comment: You mean if I populate first then query, I can combine them in one command?

Comment: There is no query after population. I mean that you can fetch ALL records using a simple `Article.find()`, and then go through each document at the application level and remove those which do not match the criteria. However this will take more time as your article collection increases in size.